# How to check if all array elements which are ids of html elements has value

Tags: jquery

I am receiving `id`s of required html `input`s in an array through ajax. Here is my HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
  <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
  <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
</form>
```

Here is the required ids:

```
var arr = ['firstName', 'email'];
```

My goal is to check if all required input has value or not. So, I have written:

```
var areSomeFieldsEmpty = false;

function checkForm() {
  $.each(arr, function(index, value){
    if($('#' + value).val().length <= 0) {
      areSomeFieldsEmpty = true;
    } else {
      areSomeFieldsEmpty = false;
    }
  });
```

But, by keeping `firstName` input empty, if I put value on `email` input, I got `false` as a value of `areSomeFieldsEmpty`. But, it should be `true`.

[image]

How to fix this?

```js
var arr = ['firstName', 'email'];

$('form').on('keyup blur change', 'input', function() {
 checkForm();
});
var areSomeFieldsEmpty = false;

function checkForm() {
  $.each(arr, function(index, value){
    if($('#' + value).val().length  <= 0) {
      areSomeFieldsEmpty = true;
    } else {
      areSomeFieldsEmpty = false;
    }
  });

  console.log(areSomeFieldsEmpty);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
  <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
  <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `each` function repeats the process for each field and return the final result.

So in the background the process is something like

areSomeFieldsEmpty = true , // on firstname

areSomeFieldsEmpty = true , // on last name

areSomeFieldsEmpty = false , // on email

and **the last** result is what you see areSomeFieldsRequired = false **or viseversa**. depending on how your application runs through the each loop. Which is usually top to bottom.

**SO** I suggest having a counter check the true or false and **increment if true** then if the counter is greater than 0 it means there was some fields empty.

And you can set the areSomeFieldsRequired = true or false once

```
function checkForm() {
var counter = 0; 
  $.each(arr, function(index, value){
    if($('#' + value).val().length  <= 0) {
      counter++;
    }
  });

  console.log(counter);
 if (counter > 0){
  areSomeFieldsEmpty = true
 }
 else {
  areSomeFieldsEmpty = false
 }
}
```

Comment: YW :) Glad to be a help :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply break the loop , return false; will break the loop, so when you get any value validated, you simple break the loop, so after areSomeFieldsEmpty = false, you will no further need the loop.

```
var areSomeFieldsEmpty = false;

function checkForm() {
  $.each(arr, function(index, value){
   if($('#' + value).val().length <= 0) {
   areSomeFieldsEmpty = true;

  } else {
   areSomeFieldsEmpty = false;
   return false;
 }
});
```

Comment: this will break the loop once it checks for the first one and the input field is not empty. It won't continue to check for any other input fields